# Сравнение дат по месяцу и дню в C#

Tags: c#, дата, linq

Помогите, пожалуйста, отфильтровать данные по дате месяца и дня. Есть некие обьекты с датой создания. Надо выбрать в диапазоне от месяц : день до месяц : день. Я выбираю и сравниваю числа месяца и дня... но если, к примеру, выбрать 20 января и 30 марта, то данные между 1 - 20 марта - февраля пропадут.

Comment: в каком формате дата создания данных объектов? в виде экземпляров DateTime?

Answer (score 5):

Тип DateTime поддерживает сравнение своих экземпляров друг с другом. Т.е., если я правильно понял вопрос, нет необходимости сравнивать отдельные свойства:

```
var fromDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 20, 0, 0, 0);
var toDate = new DateTime(2012, 03, 30, 23, 59, 59);
var filtered = from element in source
               where element.Date >= fromDate && element.Date <= endDate
               select element;
```

**UPD:** (на основе обсуждения в комментариях)

```
var fromDay = (new DateTime(2001, 01, 20, 0, 0, 0)).DayOfYear;
var toDay = (new DateTime(2001, 03, 30, 23, 59, 59)).DayOfYear;

var filtered = from element in source
               let dayOfYear = element.Date.DayOfYear
               let dayOfYearShifted =
                  (dayOfYear > 59 && DateTime.IsLeapYear(element.Date.Year)
                  ?  dayOfYear
                  : dayOfYear - 1
               where element.Date.DayOfYear >= dayOfYearShifted
                  && element.Date.DayOfYear <= dayOfYearShifted
               select element;
```

Кое-какие пояснения:

- Во fromDay и toDay можно использовать любой невисокосный год, необязательно 2001
- dayOfYear > 59 — это потому что если дата до 28 февраля включительно, то отнимать ничего не надо, даже если год високосный

Comment: синтаксис методов проще:

    var filtered = source.Whre(element => element.Date >= fromDate && element.Date <= endDate);

Comment: Не совсем правильно ...нужно не учитывать год
К примеру с 20 января по 31 марта ...моим способом мы потеряем февраль и март до 20 числа...нужно этого избежать и не учитывать год ...это может быть с 1990 до 2030 и тп

Comment: тогда сравнивайте только [DateTime.DayOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.dayofyear.aspx)

    var filtered = source.Where(element => element.Date.DayOfYear >= fromDate.DayOfYear && element.Date.DayOfYear <= endDate.DayOfYear);

Comment: Не возникнет ли при использовании DayOfYear проблема с (не)високосными годами?